# Solution of polynomial equation $g(x)\cdot g(y) = g(x)+g(y)+g(xy)-2\;\forall x,y\in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> If $g(x)$ is a polynomial function satisfying $g(x)\cdot g(y) = g(x)+g(y)+g(xy)-2\;\forall x,y\in \mathbb{R}$
>
> and $g(2)=5\;,$ Then $g(5) = $

$\bf{My\; Solution::}$ Given $$g(x)\cdot g(y)=g(x)+g(y)+g(xy)-2.................(\star)$$

$\forall x,y\; \in \mathbb{R}$ and and Given $g(2) = 5\;,$ Then $g(5)=$

Now Put $x=y=1$ in $(\star)\;,$ We get $$\left(g(1)\right)^2=3(g(1))-2$$

So we get $g(1)=1$ or $g(1) = 2$

Now put $\displaystyle y = \frac{1}{x}$ in $(\star)\;,$ We get $$g(x)\cdot g\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) = g(x)+g\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)+g(1)-2.....................(\star\star)$$

Now If we take $g(1) = 2\;,$ We get $$g(x)+g\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) = g(x)\cdot g\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$
So we Get $g(x) = 1+x^n.$

Now When we take $g(1)=1\;,$ Then $\displaystyle g(x)\cdot g\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)=g(x)+g\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)-1$

Now can I solve above functional equation, Help me, Thanks

Comment: There is a problem here because taking $x=1$ and $y=y$, then $g(1)g(y)=g(1)+2g(y)\Rightarrow g(n)=\frac{g(1)}{g(1)-2}$ so $g(1)\neq 2\Rightarrow g(1)=1$ and then $g(y)=-1$ for all $y\in R$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define $v(x) =g(x) -1 $ then we have $$v(x) v(y) -v(xy) =(g(x)-1)(g(y) -1) -g(xy) +1 = g(x) g(y) - g(x) -g(y) -g(xy) +2 =0$$
Thus the function $v$ satisfies the functional equation $$v(x) v(y) =v(xy) $$ and therefore $$v(x) =x^c $$ and since $$v(2) =4 $$ therefore $$v(x) =x^2$$ and $$g(x) = x^2 +1 $$ so $$g(5) =26 ,$$